# Access which number of trees had the lowest error when running random forest

Tags: r, random-forest, r-ranger

I am following this [example](https://uc-r.github.io/random_forests) and I want to change one part of the code from:

```
# default RF model
m1 <- randomForest(
  formula = Sale_Price ~ .,
  data    = ames_train
)

# number of trees with lowest MSE
btree <- which.min(m1$mse)
```

to it's equivalent `ranger`-based code. The issue is that `ranger` doesn't provide access directly to number of trees with the lowest MSE. How can I calculate the and store in a variable (I call this var *btree*) the number of trees with the lowest MSE?

```
library(rsample)      # data splitting 
library(randomForest) # basic implementation
library(ranger)       # a faster implementation of randomForest

set.seed(123)
ames_split <- initial_split(AmesHousing::make_ames(), prop = .7)
ames_train <- training(ames_split)
ames_test  <- testing(ames_split)

# for reproduciblity
set.seed(123)

# default RF model
m1 <- randomForest(
  formula = Sale_Price ~ .,
  data    = ames_train
)

# the equivalent in ranger
m1 <- ranger(
      formula = Sale_Price ~ .,
      data    = ames_train
    )

# number of trees with lowest MSE (randomForest package)
btree <- which.min(m1$mse)
```

Based on the `ranger` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ranger/versions/0.16.0/topics/ranger):

> prediction.error: Overall out-of-bag prediction error. For
> classification this is accuracy (proportion of misclassified
> observations), for probability estimation the Brier score, for
> regression the mean squared error and for survival one minus Harrell's
> C-index.

So if I do:

```
  m1 <- ranger(
    formula = Sale_Price ~ .,
    data    = ames_train
  )
  
  # number of trees with highest r2
  btree = which.max(m1$prediction.error)
  print(btree)
```

The result is:

```
[1] 1
```

which obviously is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to get this directly from the `ranger` outputs. But you could run predictions for each tree and calculate it yourself. For example:

```
m1 <- ranger(
  formula = Sale_Price ~ .,
  data    = ames_train,
  keep.inbag = TRUE, 
  write.forest = TRUE 
)

num_trees <- m1$num.trees
predictions <- matrix(nrow = num_trees, ncol = nrow(ames_train))
mse <- numeric(num_trees)

for(i in 1:num_trees){
  pred <- predict(m1, 
                  data = ames_train, 
                  num.trees = i)$predictions
  mse[i] <- mean((pred - ames_train$Sale_Price)^2)
}

btree <- which.min(mse)
```